# Liquid-gas phase transitions

Tags: literature-request

I am looking for books or reviews on liquid-gas phase transition, going beyond the basics covered in statistical mechanics texts (Ehrenfest classification, mainly van-der-Waals equation).

Most books on phase transitions seem to dismiss the subject as less interesting than the second order phase transitions, but perhaps there is a more complete chapter somewhere?

Another possibility is chemistry texts or texts devoted to more specific problems, like atmospheric science or water.

Related: [Phase Transitions (Statistical Mechanics) Book Recommendation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409610/247642)